# selenium test showing email already taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, automated-tests

I am running tests in my Rails 3 application.  I use rspec, capybara and Selenium RC.

I have the following test for a form:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'support/database_cleaner.rb'
describe "Greetings" do
  attr_reader :selenium_driver
  alias :page :selenium_driver

  before(:all) do
    selenium_setup
    @selenium_driver.start_new_browser_session
  end

  after(:all) do
    @selenium_driver.close_current_browser_session
    @verification_errors.should == []
  end

  describe "greeting creation" do

 before(:each) do
    @board = Factory(:board)
  end

 describe "success" do
      it "should create and display the greeting" do
           page.open "/boards/#{@board.id}"
           page.click "greeting_link"
           wait_for_ajax
           page.type "greeting_headline", "Hey Have a great day!!!"
           page.type "greeting_content", "I wish you the best birthday ever. Your are a great friend and deserve a great day."
           page.type "user_name", "Example User"
           page.type "user_email", "it@it.com"
           page.click "commit"
           wait_for_ajax
           ("Add greeting").should == page.get_text("greeting_link")
           #("Hey Have a great day!!!").should == page.get_text("css=div.headline.round")
           #page.is_text_present("Hey Have a great day!!!\n\n I wish you the best birthday ever. Your are a great friend and deserve a great day.").should be_true
           #("Hey Have a great day!!!").should == page.get_text("css=div.headline.round")
      end
    end
```

If I do this text by hand in the browser it works perfectly. 
However when I run the test it fails because the validation says that the email has already been taken.

I tried rake db:test:prepare. No joy. Same problem.

I have the database_cleaner gem installed in the test environment and have the following in my spec/support/database_cleaner.rb

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

I am at a complete loss here as I am a NOOB.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this situation fixed?

Comment: are you using devise for authentication by any chance?

Comment: No. Just using authentication I learned from Ruby on Rails tutorial. Thought it was better to really understand what I am doing first with each step before.

Answer (score 0):

two obvious possibilities then - one is that the Factory is getting called twice for some reason (in which case putting something like

`sequence(:email) {|n| "it@it#{n}.com"}`

in your factory should get round the problem.  Other possibility is that your factory defines an email address it@it.com - in which case you will get the problem when you try to save the one you create in the test

Comment: Hi Chispanda, Well I looked in my factory and I am not using the same email.  In fact I am not using a factory for the user for this test. And I call just this test. Even after I do rake db:test:prepare I am getting this same error. I really don't know where the email is getting written to cause this.

Comment: Wild guess now ... and you are sure that your call to  @board = Factory(:board) is not creating a user (or some other entity with an email address) that is causing the validation to fail?  I'm guessing that maybe a Board has_many users/people and that in the factory perhaps you have something like f.association :user, :factory => :user

Comment: I swear I am not creating a user. What I have discovered is that the uniqueness validation seems to be getting activated for no apparent reason. I have another test using selenium that saves a users name and birthday. It works fine. But when I put the uniqueness validation it gave me the same error that the name was already taken.  The question is what is wrong with my selenium setup that it triggers this validation?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your selenium setup which is why I went down the 'must be doing something dumb' route - not being rude, we've all been there :-)  I have pretty much an identical setup and don't see this sort of problem.  Sorry not to be more help

Comment: It's mega weird and wish I could fix it. I have recreated the tests and its still the same problem. It seems to be creating duplicates. Is it database_cleaner?

Comment: well, fwiw here is what I have in my config block - actually I'll put it in an answer so it's more readable

Answer (score 0):

Here is my config block - config.use_transactional_fixtures = false`

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end

config.before(:each) do
  if example.metadata[:js]
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  else
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
  if example.metadata[:js]
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end
end
```

end`

I don't really see why that would make a difference, but it might be worth dropping it into yours and giving it a whirl ...

Comment: Thanks chrispanda you have gone above and beyond your duty. I applied the code above but same problem. There must be a ghost in my machine.

Comment: I used your code and tried it again. What I now understand about Selenium is that when it tests it tests the rails app and knows nothing about the database. I need to set up a separate system just for Selenium and point that environment to a test database and then it will all work. Mystery is what database cleaner is supposed to do because it is not cleaning out my development database.  If I could run rake db:reset or rake db:erase from within  my rspec selenium test then all would be well in the universe